# LINQ to Entities on (database != Microsoft SQL Server)

Tags: database, linq-to-entities

My production is on full blown SQL Server 2008.

I would like to have **integration tests with some light weight database** that

- doesn't have to be installed on the machine and
- doesn't run as a service

...if at all possible.

I use LINQ to Entities in my code that probably makes this goal even more complicated.

Is it possible to use any lightweight DB to accomplish this goal? Do those DBs have LINQ providers or whatever they're called to translate LINQ to actual queries...

**Anybody has any experience with LINQ to Entities with third party databases?**

Comment: LINQ to Entities... that's too bad because if you are using NHibernate, you can simply switch on sqlite support during test time for testing purpose, and switch on SQL server during deployment time.

Comment: Yes but I would barely use LINQ to Objects in NHibernate case wouldn't I? Not even LINQ to SQL/NH...

Comment: @Ngu Soon Hui: LINQ to Entities works with any ADO.NET provider, does it not?

Comment: @John: I don't think so. Because it needs a provider that translates LINQ to actual T-SQL query that actually gets sent to the database.

Comment: @Robert: Have you looked at the queries it generates? Pretty standard SQL. Few, if any, Microsoft extensions required.

Comment: @John: Well some lightweight databases don't support sub queries that are quite common in L2EF... But I guess I could give it a try.

Comment: @John: Why don't you put your commented observations in an answer, because I'd vote it up. All legitimate suggestions even though they are not talking about particular DBs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about SQL Server 2008 Express? That's about as lightweight as a SQL Server 2008 compatible system gets. It's basically a light-weight workstation install for SQL Server - it's a server, it's a service in the background. http://www.microsoft.com/express/sql/default.aspx

There's also SQL Server Compact 3.5 which should be compatible with SQL Server 2008, but I don't know if it's supported by the Entity Framework as a store. This is just a bunch of DLLs you need to add to your project, and it stores all its data in a single .sdf file. http://www.microsoft.com/Sqlserver/2005/en/us/compact.aspx

Marc

Comment: I'd like to avoid installing SQL Express. In this case I'd install Standard edition. But I'd like to avoid database installations for integration testing.

Comment: Then I'd suggest you have a good look at SQL Server Compact - hopefully, it support Entity Framework - no installs needed here, AFAIK

Comment: @Robert: how is it integration testing when you're not integrating with a database that's in any way like the one you'll really use?

Comment: @John. Underlying RDBMS should be similar to SQL Server. Schema will always be the same. But you may be right. There may be security issues that may make integration tests irrelevant.

Comment: There are some SQL CE limitations when used with Entity Framework. See here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc835494.aspx - in particular, no server-generated keys, and no `Skip` and `Take`.